# Query to Get List of Missing Sequential Numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have a query I set up that looks at an orders table, and gets a list of missing sequential order numbers, so we can use the list to help track missing orders.
It seems to be working fine, except that I am only getting the first number if there is more than one in a row.
So, if the result should be: 1,5,6,10
I instead get: 1,5,10
6 is left out

I am no SQL master, and I can't quite figure out what to change in the code to make sure I get all of them.  Here is the code I have:

```
DECLARE @maxorder INT
SET @maxorder = (SELECT MAX(CAST(TranNo) AS INT)
FROM SalesOrder 
WHERE TranDate 
BETWEEN getdate()-1 AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
SELECT a.offset AS Missing
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS Offset
UNION
SELECT CAST((TranNo) AS INT) + 1
FROM SalesOrder
WHERE TranDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-1 AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT CAST((TranNo) AS INT) AS TranNum 
FROM SalesOrder 
WHERE TranDate BETWEEN getdate()-1 AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())) b 
ON a.offset = b.trannum
WHERE 
a.offset > 1 
AND b.trannum IS NULL
AND a.offset < @maxorder
ORDER BY Missing
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL?  With the later versions there are some very easy ways to solve this.

Comment: Also some sample data would be helpful, along with what you expect to see based on that data.

Comment: Get min and max number. Fill the temp table with the entire range. Than left/right join the two with condition of null on your data. You will see all missing records

Comment: Sample data: 86092, 86094, 86101  Expected: 86092, 86094, 86095, 86096, 86101

Comment: TS, I'm not 100% sure how to do that.  I'm not exactly a pro at SQL.  I'll see if I can figure it out.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Caldrumr `DavidN` in his answer did exactly what I described

Comment: Yes, thanks again.  You guys were very helpful.  I appreciate the education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @maxorder INT, @counter INT = 1 --Set this to your lower bound for SalesOrder table

SELECT @maxorder = MAX(CAST(TranNo AS INT))
FROM SalesOrder

CREATE TABLE #temp (TranNum INT)

WHILE @counter <= @maxorder
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp (TranNum) values (@counter)
END

SELECT t.TranNum
FROM #temp t
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrder s ON t.TranNum = CAST(s.TranNo AS INT)
WHERE s.TranNo is null
ORDER BY t.TranNum
```

Comment: Thank you.  This got me started toward fixing the issue.  I appreciate it!  I used a table variable instead of a temp table, and added and moved a few things, and it works like a charm.  Awesome!